# Redirect command output which waits for user input

Tags: powershell, user-input, io-redirection

Is it possible to redirect a command output that waits for user input (with or without redirecting that input), and without knowing in advance that user input will be requested?

i.e. when running this command with powerhell.exe:

```
chkdsk C: /F /R | Tee -var test
```

the output is:

```
CHKDSK ne peut pas s'exécuter parce que le volume est utilisé
par un autre processus. Voulez-vous que ce volume soit
```

instead of:

```
CHKDSK ne peut pas s’exécuter parce que le volume est utilisé
par un autre processus. Voulez-vous que ce volume soit
vérifié au prochain redémarrage du système ? (O/N)
```

Using cmd.exe, when redirecting output to a file, it just waits for user input without showing anything.

Comment: Well, this depends on the (non-native) `Tee` command tool you are using; I guess yours only displays completed lines on the console...

Comment: @aschipfl The same problem occurs when using standard redirection to a file, nothing is shown because it waits for user input.

Comment: You would need to actually provide some input to the command in order to get the lines to echo to a pipe `|` or at all in a `FOR`.  You can usually get around this by specifying an input and echoing it to the CMD, or redirecting a file to the command BUT ONLY IF the command accepts that form of input from the CLI.  EG: `ECHO(N|chkdsk C: /F /R | Tee -var test`

Comment: @aschipfl: Good point; re `Tee`: The command is a PowerShell command, and `Tee` is a built-in alias for the `Tee-Object` cmdlet (on Windows).

Comment: @Deaudouce, redirection (or pipes) does not kind of hold back data until a line of text is complete; imagine redirecting binary data, where there is concept of lines...

Comment: Okay, I see, thanks. I will try the `Transcript` method then.

Answer (score 1):

Capturing output from interactive console applications is problematic.

The first is caused by the nature of console applications in general: Lines that prompt the user for input don't tend to have a newline at the end because they rely on the echoed newline from the user *input* to complete the line. The effect you'll see in the output file is that lines with user input will be joined with the next line.

Secondly, PowerShell will do line-based buffering in the pipeline and so you won't see the output of any partial lines (the lines that prompt for user input) until after you enter the input. PowerShell does not provide a way to configure this as far as I'm aware and there's not much you can do about it.

### Transcripts

It could be that the best solution is to use a [transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript). It captures both `stdin` and `stdout` so that the file looks like what your screen looked like.

To store a transcript to `output.txt`:

```
Start-Transcript output.txt
chkdsk C: /F /R
Stop-Transcript
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there a reliable way to extract the output from the file, or will it be using the number of lines or `*****` separators? And is there an equivalent for `cmd`?